# Autowired in WS not working Spring

Tags: spring

I have implemented a WS using Jax-ws in my server project and I'm making the calls to the service from a client application. The problem is that if I want to use @Autowire inside my @WebService annotated class it always throws the following error:

InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class com.myco.wsserver.LeaveRequestEndPoint;

if I debug that class, the reference to my autowired bean is null. if I remove the bean from my @webservice annotated class it works , also if  I get the application context manually and then get the bean it also works, but I would like to know why I can't Autowire any bean.

Here is my code.

WebService class:

```
@WebService(serviceName="LeaveRequestHandler")
public class LeaveRequestEndPoint extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport{

    @Autowired
    GenericBean mBean;

    public LeaveRequestEndPoint(GenericBean mBean){
        this.mBean = mBean;
    }


    @WebMethod(operationName="executeOperation")
    public String getText() {
        return mBean.getText();

    }
}
```

application context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="genericBean" class="com.myco.wsserver.GenericBean"/>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Class constructor is called before injection happens. It is not the way of constructing classes using spring. There is `@PostConstruct` annotation guarantees injections are ready while class is constructing, or constructor injection can be used.

Constructor is now a proper one. Injection is done after the constructor run.

You have 2 options.

1. Move @Autowired annotation to constructor. (Constructor injection)

   @Autowired
   public LeaveRequestEndPoint(GenericBean mBean)
2. Remove constructor and use setter getter injection. (setter getter injection)

`GenericBean mBean;` has default access modifier that's why your injection fails. Change `mBean` to private and add setter getters.

```
@Autowired
private GenericBean mBean;

public setMBean(GenericBean mBean)
{
this.mBean = mBean;
}
public getMBean()
{
return this.mbean;
}
```

Comment: As you  have suggested I have added the setter and getter but it throws the same error

Comment: Oww sorry. please see my edits. You have a class constructor which is called before injection happens.